# Update the Content Security Policy in Meteor app without forking boilerplate-generator package?

Tags: cordova, security, meteor, content-security-policy, boilerplate

I have a cordova app developed using Meteor, and I've run into a situation where I need to update the Content Security Policy to work with one of the cordova plugins. (I need to add 'cdvfile:*' to the 'default-src' rule.) As far as I can tell though, the Content Security Policy is hard coded into the boilerplate generator package and can not be overriden simply by adding a second Content Security policy in the head of my app template.

Is there a way to update the Content Security Policy in a Meteor app without forking the boilerplate-generator package?

Comment: You can define your own content security policy, this package may be what you need. https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/browser-policy

Comment: Thanks. I came across that package previously but had assumed that it would only affect the browser CSP. The boilerplate generator has a separate browser and cordova template. I'll give that a shot and see if it applies across the board.

Comment: Right, I didn't realise it was  a specific package. Cloning the repo and putting it inside the packages folder of your app is really simple, and then you can make any changes you like. You can simply change the version number or put your own github id on it and it just builds like everything else. I have several packages that I have forked, and a few of my own too.

Comment: Understood. I'm just trying to avoid an additional variation to have to track going forward. Ideally, I could fix it someplace once and not have to worry about updates to a package going forward. BUT, obviously, if that's the only way to do it, than I'll go that route.

Comment: I tried creating a local version of the boilerplate-generator package but it doesn't appear to be taking my changes. I added 'cdvfile:' to the CSP in the cordova template, but the old version of the CSP persists when I run the iOS simulator.